# Adding WCF webservice Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

So I see Xamarin Studio has a feature to add webservices. So I add a webservice but when I try and build the project the generated reference file gives some compile errors.

[image]

When adding a webservice the project will automatically add the dll's. But what I don't understand is that the namespaces are used in the reference file and yet the classes are not recognised even though the correct dll's are imported in the project. And secondly there are two reference files.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the solution.

Basically you can't add webservices in your PCL in Xamarin Studio using the "Add Web Reference" feature, Xamarin Studio does not do this correctly.

You would need to use Visual Studio add the reference the same way and now it works :)